# Need WCF Clarification on client/server operations

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client

I need to have a C# NET Server application and C# NET Client application. Using an ASP web interface for the server, I will need to be able to tell a specific client application to do functions such as DownloadFile(string url), CreateWindowsService(), etc.

Would I do something like the following on the server and expose them to the client applications?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFunctions
{
  [OperationContract]
  void DownloadFile(string url);
  void CreateWindowsService();
  void OtherFunctions();
}
```

From what I have read, it sounds like I define/code functions on the server, then the client applications actually run the functions as if it was coded into them?

On another note, after reading over the descriptions of the bindings, it sounds like I should use Tcp for this project? Each client application will be on a seperate machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the operations are run on the server, the result of the operation (if not void) is sent to the client in a serialized format.

**Edit**
When you add a WCF reference to the client a proxy is generated with methods that has the same signature as the server contract. Each proxy method encodes its input parameters in a serialized form and sends them over to the server. The server decodes the request, executes the method on the server and returns the answer. The client decodes the answer into regular c# types and finally returns from the proxy method.

Comment: Sow how would I do something like what I described above then? I would need the File downloaded to the client machines, or the service created on the client. Would I have to do it backwards and make all of the clients servers, and have the actual "server" application function as a client in WCF?

Comment: @Brett, `DownloadFile` would return the file content as a string to the client. `CreateWindowsService` is impossible since a web application does not have permissions to create services.

Comment: @Brett, at least for the Service creation part you need a client application created that can run with full trust. It can be created with WinForms, WPF or similar.

Comment: I apologize, I believe I forgot to mention that both my Server and Client are console applications. That confused me when you mentioned that I would not be able to do it.

Comment: @Brett, then you need to clarify what you mean with "ASP Web interface", hmm, do you try to create a bunch of clients listening to a configuration server and that server is controlled via a web interface?

Comment: In that case you either have to put the "servers on the clients" or have a look at the [wsDualHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx), or have the client polling the server at regular intervals to find out if they are expecting to perform any operations.

Comment: Thank you Albin, that answers the question!